# ¿Cómo creo una tabla con el campo fecha con el formato dd/MM/yyyy?

Tags: sql, sql-server

En `SQL Server` el formato por defecto de `DATE` es `yyyy/MM/dd`.

Lo que quiero es cambiar este formato a `dd/MM/yyyy` al momento de crear la tabla. ¿Es posible? Si es así, ¿cómo?

Comment: dónde ves que ése sea el formato por defecto para `DATE`?, a qué te refieres exactamente?

Comment: Te diré una cosa: **no hagas eso**. En SQL existen varias funciones para dar un formato de salida adecuado a tus datos. Si tú intentas forzar otro formato de fechas que no es el standard, aparte de que te puede resultar cuesta arriba hacerlo, tu base de datos tendrá datos que podrían ser incompatibles con datos provenientes de otra base de datos por ejemplo, o de otras fuentes.

Comment: Coincido con el comentario de @A.Cedano, no realices cambios sobre el formato ya establecido por tu motor de base de datos. Cuando generes tus reportes o uses un aplicativo para tomar los datos, podrás usar alguna de las muchas funciones que te permiten formatear el campo como lo desees. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### El núcleo de la pregunta

> Lo que quiero es cambiar este formato a dd/MM/yyyy **al momento de crear la tabla**. ¿Es posible? Si es así, ¿cómo?

### Respuesta

**No es posible si declaras tu columna del tipo `DATE` o del tipo `DATETIME`.**

### ¿Por qué no es posible?

Porque una cosa es el formato (que tiene que ver con la manera de presentar los datos) y otra cosa es la manera en que el manejador de base de datos almacena esos datos. En el `CREATE TABLE` tú no tienes acceso a alterar la forma en que se ha diseñado el manejador para almacenar esos datos (y aunque pudieras no sería para nada conveniente). Si ya es trabajoso mantener por ejemplo un campo `VARCHAR` que manejase representaciones de fechas (ver final de la respuesta), imagínate la dificultad si se alterase la estructura interna de los datos.

SQL Server almacena los valores [`DATETIME` como un campo de 8 bytes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql), con un rango entre 1753-01-01 a 9999-12-31, con una precisión de 0.00333 segundos.

Según [esta respuesta de Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143266/5587982):

> Los primeros 4 bytes almacenan el número de días desde la época de SQL
>   Server (1 de enero de 1900) y los otros 4 bytes almacenan el número de
>   instantes después de la medianoche, donde un "instante" es de 3,3 milisegundos.
>   Los primeros cuatro bytes están firmados (pueden ser positivos o
>   negativos), lo que explica por qué se pueden representar las fechas
>   anteriores a la época (1 de enero de 1900).

### ¿Y si de todos modos quiero hacerlo?

Si de todos modos quieres almacenar las fechas en ese formato, tendrás que crear una columna del tipo `VARCHAR`, y trabajar **arduamente** durante toda tu aplicación para:

- Dar mantenimiento a ese formato
- Controlar errores de inserción (como que alguien quiera poner que nación el `40-50-1845454`, el día 40 del mes 50 del año 1845454).
- Hacer cálculos entre fechas (tendrás que hacer conversiones constantes de cadenas a objetos fecha reales para que los cálculos no fallen)
- ... y muchos dolores de cabeza más.  Y eso, no hablemos si hay que almacenar valores de horas/minutos/segundos/milisegundos.

### Recomendación final

Dejar las cosas como están y valerte de cualquiera de las funciones existentes para presentar tus fechas/horas en el formato que quieras.

`DD-MM-YYYY` no es más que una representación de los datos y existen múltiples funciones para lograrla con suma facilidad.

Querer alterar la estructura de un campo que maneje fechas tan solo por el formato no tiene sentido. Es como si quisieras que un campo `VARCHAR` te almacenara las letras en color rojo (el color es un formato, un atributo de salida). Cuando quieras ese texto en negro o en otro color tendrás que añadir un trabajo suplementario para conseguirlo y eso tendrá su precio.

---

**PD**: A quienes votan en contra, agradecería un comentario sobre el motivo del voto negativo, para poder mejorar la respuesta.

Comment: No creo que se pueda cambiar el formato por defecto que devuelve el motor de base de datos para las fechas, y mucho menos para una tabla, lo que se puede hacer son 2 cosas, [convertir la fecha](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) al momento de la consulta, o crear una vista de la tabla con una consulta que haga lo mismo. Por otro lado, en la inserción o utilización de expreciones con fechas, las mismas pueden estar en distintos formatos como Strings y son eventualmente convertidas (al menos los formatos mas comunes).

Comment: Véase [esto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Donde refieres formato por defecto entiendo que te refieras al formato en el que estás recibiendo la fecha en las consultas. Internamente SQL Server se encarga de realizar la codificación necesaria para almacenar la fecha, intentar modificar estos parámetros lo considero personalmente un error.

Lo que yo considero que deberías hacer es utilizar las funciones que provee para obtener la fecha en el formato correcto. Estas dependen de la versión que estés utilizando, a continuación tienes todas las funciones disponibles para cada version: (No olvides seleccionar tu versión para no volverte loco)

[CAST y CONVERT (Transact-SQL))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx)

En tu caso si tienes la versión mas reciente de SQL Server podrías utilizar:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(), 101)
```

de esta forma obtendrías la fecha en el formato que nos comentas.