# Cambiar el modelo de fecha de la base Datos AAA/MM/dd a dd/MM/AAA

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

Buenas Quisiera saber si es posible cambiar el modelo de las fechas desde el mismo wampserver

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y no es más simple que la formatees donde la necesites ver?

Comment: No es posible, y no es conveniente. Existen multitud de funciones para formatear los datos como los quieras presentar. El almacenamiento de las fechas tiene una estructura propia en las bases de datos, el cual no es posible alterar. Y aunque se pudiera, no sería recomendable. Para más detalles [puedes consultar esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130145/29967), no es específica de MySQL, pero también es válida.

Answer (score 1):

creo que tendrias que ponerlo así.

DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Nacimiento, "%d/%m/%Y") pero eso seria a la hora de consultar/mostrar, no a la hora de guardar

Comment: se gracias bro, pero en si tengo guardar y hacer consultar. En la estructura de la base de datos la columna Fecha, la pongo de tipo Date y me da ese formato por defecto, es posible cambiar ese formato por defecto que te da wampserver?