# Cambiar formato del input date

Tags: php, html, mysqli

me gustaría saber como cambiar el formato de un input tipo date

Tengo este input en el que se muestra dd-mm-yyyy

```html
<p>Fecha <input type="date" name="fecha" required></p>
```

Pero a la hora de hacer el registro con php en mi base de datos *(la columna en la que se registra es en formato de texto)* aparece en formato yyyy-mm-dd.

¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Comment: Y de que formato es que lo necesitas?

Comment: Necesito que en mi bd se registre así dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Cual es el tipo de dato de la columna donde guardas la fecha?

Comment: varchar(100) utf8_general_ci

Comment: Tefef  leyendo este comentario tuyo: *Necesito que en mi bd se registre así dd-mm-yyyy*, quiero advertir que hacer eso sería un grave error. Recomendaría que guardes los datos en la forma natural en que lo hace la base de datos, es decir, `yyyy-mm-dd`. De lo contrario, tendrás [muchos problemas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130145/29967) cuando tengas que mantener los datos, o hacer cálculos con ellos, etc. Además, los DBMS tienen muchas funciones para formatear los datos como quieras, en la salida. **Guardar datos formateados es matarlos**.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si tú guardas el dato del tipo `DATETIME` la base de datos lo guardará siempre así: `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS`. Ese dato te ofrecerá todas las ventajas: guardar fecha y hora en una sola columa, hacer cálculos exactos, impedir introducir fechas erróneas... con un `VARCHAR` controlar eso es un dolor de cabeza. Y si quieres calcular, ¡tendrás que convertir a fecha un dato que debía ser fecha desde siempre! En cambio, para darle formato, basta con hacer algo como esto: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%d/%m/%Y') AS mifecha ...` o puedes darle formato en el código PHP también.

Comment: Apoyo totalmente lo que dice @Cedano. No es bueno guardar las fechas como otro tipo de campo que no sea date/datetime porque eliminas todas las funcionalidades que te ofrecen los gestores de base de datos para tratar con este tipo de datos. Analizando a profundidad si estuviese correcto guardar en varchar entonces para por qué se existe el tipo date/datetime? Existe precisamente para facilitar ciertas operaciones comúnes que se deben realizar con este tipo de datos... comparaciones de fechas, transformaciones etc

Answer (score 1):

No se puede cambiar el formato de un `input[date]`, no por lo menos hasta la fecha de hoy. Lo que si puedes hacer darle le formato que deseas antes de guardar la fecha.

Puedes lograrlo utilizando [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/), convertirla a un objeto `momentjs` y luego darle el formato deseado:

```js
function obtenerFecha(e)
{

  var fecha = moment(e.value);
  console.log("Fecha original:" + e.value);
  console.log("Fecha formateada es: " + fecha.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="date" onchange="obtenerFecha(this)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Si el front tiene el formato tal cual lo necesitas, simplemente cambia ese formato en el back para guardarlo como desees en tu base de datos.

Asumiendo que tu campo es varchar como lo has dicho.

```
$fecha = new DateTime('2006-12-30');
echo $fecha->format('d-m-Y');
```

En su defecto podría ser así:

```
$fecha = new DateTime($_POST['fecha']);
echo $fecha->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

El formato de los `inputs` de tipo `date` lo renderiza el navegador:

> The control's UI varies in general from browser to browser; at the
>   moment support is patchy, see Browser compatibility for further
>   details. In unsupported browsers, the control degrades gracefully to a
>   simple .

[Fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

[Más info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Por tanto, no se puede cambiar directamente el formato si tu `input` sigue siendo de tipo `date`. Si no es mucho problema, lo mejor es que lo declares como tipo `text` y utilices Javascript para darle el formato buscado (con un datepicker de jQuery o Bootstrap, por ejemplo)

Comment: pff.. pues entonces tendré que hacerlo con js..

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en las bases de datos si usas el tipo **date o datetime** te guardara **yyyy-mm-dd**si deseas obtenerlo **dd-mm-yyyy** debes guardarlo en un campo tipo **varchar**

Comment: lo tengo en varchar

Answer (score 0):

Veo que en las etiquetas estas usando php, puedes dejar el html igual pero en php utilizas la funcion date:
 `date('d-m-Y',strtotime(/*nombre de tu campo fecha*/$fecha ));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="date" type="date" value="2019-01-01">
```

```js
var fecha=document.getElementById("date").value;
 var resFecha = fecha.split("-");
 var reversedFecha = resFecha.reverse(); 
 var FechaOb=reversedFecha.join('-');
alert(FechaOb);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar cómo este código soluciona el problema descrito por @Pelukosa?

Answer (score -3):

Debes definirle el pattern que requieres:

```html
 <input type="date"  pattern="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}" required/>
```

Comment: Esa solución no funciona. El atributo pattern es una expresión regular que debe cumplir el input de tipo text pero en ningún caso sirve para formatear un input de tipo date.