# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato de fecha y hora en phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Tengo un campo como tipo `datetime` en una tabla y los registros me los muestra en este formato:

*YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00*

Tengo entendido que es posible modificar eso al entrar en la estructura de una tabla cualquiera, editar el campo y en la pestaña donde dice:

***Transformación de visualización en el navegador***, dejarlo establecido como:

*Date Format (text/plain: DateFormat)*

Pero en ***Opciones de transformación de visualización en el navegador*** no sé muy bien que poner para que me muestre la fecha y la hora en este formato:

***DD-MM-YYYY 00:00:00***

Menciono que ya probé con esto:

0,'%d-%m-%Y','local'

Pero me muestra solamente la **fecha** y no la **fecha junto con la hora** que es lo que quiero mostrar.

Incluyo además la siguiente imagen que encontré que es como quiero que me muestre la fecha y la hora, presten atención a la columna hora_inicio así es como me gustaría que quedase en mi base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría poder hacerlo sin código, simplemente modificar alguna opción dentro de MyPHPadmin.

Comment: *así es como me gustaría que quedase en mi base de datos...* Si quedara así sería un error, además es imposible si la columna es tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`. [Lee esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130145/29967), es SQL Server, pero aplica también para este caso. Las fechas se guardan en formato `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` **por definición interna del manejador** y así debe ser. Si se permitiera el tipo de cambios que propones los datos dislocados en columnas de tipo fecha serían una eterna fuente de problemas. Si te interesa **un formato diferente en la salida** existen funciones para ello.

Comment: Por ejemplo, puedes usar la función **[`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)** de este modo: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(columna_fecha, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') fecha FROM tabla;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fíjate en el formato que usaste: `0,'%d-%m-%Y','local'`

Esto es "Día, Mes y Año" con el formato `03-10-2018.` Ahora si quieres agregar la hora, también tienes que añadirla al formato:

```
0,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S','local'
```

Fíjate ahora en H M y S que indican "Hora, Minutos y Segundos". Ahora la fecha se muestra con el formato `03-10-2018 11:13:45`.

Comment: Probé aquello y funciona como esperaba, gracias.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya funcionado, saludos!