# Guardar en base de datos formato fecha dd mm yyyy

Tags: php, javascript, html

```html
<div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="inputBox">
                  <div class="inputText">*Fecha Activacion</div>
                  <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="date" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="inputBox">
                  <div class="inputText">*Fecha de corte</div>
                  <input type="date" id="fecha_cor" name="fecha_cor" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="date" readonly required>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Tengo estos dos input que necesito guardar sus valores en formato dd mm yyyy en mi base de datos, actualmente los guarda por yyyy mm dd.

Comment: En qué base de datos? Cómo los guardas? Por favor incluye esta información editando tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo esta guardando como tipo Date lo mas seguro.

Answer (score 3):

No cometas nunca el error de guardar una fecha formateada en la base de datos. El formato es algo muy muy relativo, si guardas la fecha formateada la misma no te servirá para nada más que para representar ese formato. Si más adelante se requiere otro formato en base a ese mismo dato, no podrás reutilizarlo. Y de hacerlo, tendrás que recurrir a funciones de conversión, complicando la lógica del programa y recargando más al servidor.

Igualmente, si necesitas hacer cálculos con esa fecha tendrás que hacer una conversión primero, con todas las complicaciones que ello conlleva.

Y todo ello porque no podrás declarar esa columna de tipo `DATETIME`, ya que siempre el formato soportado en los manejadores de base de datos es `AñoMesDia`. Es un estándar que hay que respetar si quieres sacar el máximo provecho a tus datos.

Lo más lógico y más simple es guardar la fecha en una columna `DATETIME` y en consecuencia en formato `AñoMesDia`. Luego, en cualquier contexto en que necesites la fecha formateada como sea, extraes el dato y le aplicas el formato que necesites.

Lo que es preciso entender es que el formato es algo que tiene que ver con la salida de los datos, con el contexto en que se vayan a usar. Una fecha puede tener mil maneras de representarla por tanto, a la hora de guardar los datos de tipo fecha debes olvidarte totalmente del formato y guardarlo de la forma específica, que no es otra que `AñoMesDia`.

Para más detalles, puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130145/29967).

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en la base de datos si usas el tipo date o datetime te guardara yyyy-mm-dd, si deseas obtenerlo dd-mm-yyyy debes guardarlo en un campo tipo varchar.

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format.

[The DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Ahora asumiendo que tu campo es varchar.

```
$fecha = new DateTime('2006-12-30');
echo $fecha->format('d-m-Y');
```

En su defecto podría ser así:

```
$fecha = new DateTime($_POST['fecha']);
echo $fecha->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer esto en tu archivo php donde guardas los datos.

$originalDate = "2016-11-18";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));

Espero sea de ayuda!!

Puedes checar la funcion strtotime en la documentación de php.
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php

Y tu campo en al base de datos debe ser tipo varchar ya como te mencionan si utilizas el tipo date te lo seguira guardando con el formato YYYY-MM-DD.