# cambiar fecha NOW() sentencia preparada

Tags: mysql, sql

No encuentro en sangoogle como cambiar el formato de fecha en una sentencia preparada, la BD registra la fecha y hora bien en el campo fecha/datetime pero quiero que se ajuste a los estandares españoles, es decir día mes año o 02/11/2019 en vez de 2019/11/02.

```
if ($stmt = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios_sbr (nombre, username, password, email, fecAlta, activation_code) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)'))
```

> ¿Alguien me dice como cambio el formato?

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer eso? Sería un error, porque la base de datos maneja las fechas en el formato `YYYYMMDD`. Si lo cambias tendrás que declarar la columna `VARCHAR` y luego complicarte la vida. El formato es algo relativo, que depende del contexto donde necesites los datos. Mejor guárdalo `YYYYMMDD` y cuando vayas a usar la fecha la formateas. [Te dejo esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/303682/29967) donde doy más detalles sobre esto. Sería un grave error que guardes una fecha formateada.

Comment: Ok ya comprendi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El campo en tu base de datos al ser de tipo `DATETIME` tiene un formato predeterminado el cual es:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Entonces deberías mantener ese formato aplicable a las fechas con horas para poder realizar operaciones con ellas.

Para lograr lo que deseas deberías aplicar la solución **pero a nivel de la presentación de datos, es decir en la vista**.

Por ejemplo al obtener la fecha formateada en el `SELECT`

```
SET @fecha = "2019/11/02 19:45:59";

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@fecha, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS Fecha;
```

Dando esto como resultado:

```
     Fecha
02/11/2019 19:45:59
```

Donde:

- Como primer parámetro pasamos el nombre de la columna o variable que almacena las fechas
- Como segundo parámetro le asignamos entre comillas el formato que debe seguir para construir la estructura de salida

**Referencias**

- [date_format mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
- [datatype datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Exacto. Eso es lo que debería hacer. Es un error querer guardar una fecha forzando el formato.

Comment: Gracias Aprendiz y @A. Cedano. Bien ya entendí, que en la BD se quede tal cual la inserta NOW(), luego en el frontend si quiero mostrarla escribo el codigo (como en el ejemplo) para mostrarla a mi gusto. Entendido, gracias.

Comment: De hecho puedes pensar que la fecha en bbdd es algo abstracto. Tú percibes el formato que te muestra el cliente (phpMyAdmin, MySQL workbench, etc)

Comment: Hola buenos dias! Bueno primero disculpas y pido paciencia ya que no se hacer nada de esto, solo sigo pasos de lo que busco en foros y blogs etc. Ahora bien, ¿Y si quiero mostrar la fecha del dia actual por un lado y la fecha (origen) del día que se registro el usuario por otro? en su panel de usuario por ejemplo, ¿como he de proceder con la segunda o fecha (origen), nueva columna con nuevo atributo o como? La actual ya la imprimo en el front end. Gracias

Comment: Cabe precisar que el formato predeterminado para fecha es con `-`.

Comment: buena observación @Sal lo corrijo al momento

Comment: Aprendiz, hola! Veo que rechazaste una propuesta de modificación de wiki con el argumento de _Es un intento de respuesta, alterando el contenido original, si se desea aportar mas es mejor publicar una respuesta nueva_ https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/183591 Nótese que es cambio de wiki, luego esto no aplicaría! Gracias

Comment: @fedorqui hola buen día te agradezco la observación y aclaración al respecto. Saludos